# Simplifying array diff code using syntax sugar

Tags: coffeescript

Can I simplify this array diff code, using some coffeescript syntax sugar I didn't know about?

```
first  = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4},{id:5}]
second = [{id:3},{id:4},{id:5},{id:6},{id:7}]

first = first.filter (first_element) ->
  second = second.filter (second_element) ->
    if first_element.id == second_element.id
      first_element.remove = second_element.remove = true
    return !second_element.remove?
  return !first_element.remove?

console.log(first.concat second) # [{id:1},{id:2},{id:6},{id:7}]
```

Comment: is it necessary to have no remove property on the remaining objects? this wouldn't add syntactic shugar, but gets rid of a few lines. Also, you can get rid of the `return`s and replace `==` with `is` and `true` with `on` but that's not sugar, more icing.

Comment: It is not necessary to have no remove property on the remaining objects.

Comment: Do you need the `remove` at all?

Comment: No. I just tried to figure out how to diff array of objects by property value using as little code as possible without ruining readability and came to `remove` as a result. I actually interested in both "as little code as possible" and "+ without ruining readability" solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one translates to exactly the same javascript:

```
first  = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4},{id:5}]
second = [{id:3},{id:4},{id:5},{id:6},{id:7}]

first = first.filter (first_element) ->
  second = second.filter (second_element) ->
    first_element.remove = second_element.remove = yes if first_element.id is second_element.id
    !second_element.remove?
  !first_element.remove?

console.log(first.concat second) # [{id:1},{id:2},{id:6},{id:7}]
```

The explicit `return`s were removed, the `if` was put at the end of the line. `yes` is replaced with `true` and `==` is replaced with `is`.

While not shorter in lines, this one preserves the objects in the Arrays:

```
first = first.filter (firstElement) ->
  keepFirst = yes
  second = second.filter (secondElement) ->
    keepFirst = (keepSecond  =  secondElement.id isnt firstElement.id) and keepFirst
    keepSecond
  keepFirst
```

Note that you can't use the `and=` operator, because it short cirquits.